# How to copy CsvConfiguration including class maps

Tags: csvhelper

Because I have multiple csv to parse, I have default configuration and I need to copy [CsvConfiguration](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration/Configuration/) object from [CsvHelper library](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/). The problem is Maps property of type [ClassMapCollection](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/api/CsvHelper.Configuration/ClassMapCollection). Its only access to ClassMaps is indexer, so I cannot enumerate registered maps. I managed to workaround this using reflection:

```cs
        private static Dictionary<Type, ClassMap> GetMaps(ClassMapCollection collection)
        {
            var type = collection.GetType();
            var fieldInfo = type.GetField("data", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            var dict = (Dictionary<Type, ClassMap>) fieldInfo?.GetValue(collection);

            return dict;
        }
```

Is there a reason for hiding these maps? Maybe I missed something?

Comment: Maybe you could give a little more information about what you are trying to do.  Why do you need to get the registered maps? Is the default configuration something you could pass to each csvhelper object that needs it?

Comment: Yes I have csv stream from network and I need to parse csv multiple times. Some of packages have csv header included and some don't. So I need change one property not affecting default instance.